# Interceptor dont capture some errors

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular-http-interceptors

I'm having a problem, implement in my application Ionic 3 (angular 5) interceptor for the authentication of the apis I consume. I am forcing the failure by adding another string to the Bearer, something that is invalid and can capture the errors, however, in the first instance it works, more in the second call it does not fall into the error (however the api responds an error 403)

```
addAuthHeader(request) {
return request.clone({
  setHeaders: {
    "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + _.get(this.localStorageService.getAccessToken(), 'accessToken', '')
  }
 });
}

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
//console.log(_.get(req, 'url', ''));
console.log(req);
return next.handle(req).pipe(catchError(err => {
  if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {

    let statusError = _.get(err, 'status', 0);


    console.log(err);

    if (statusError == 401 || statusError == 403) {
      return this.authProvider.loginPartnerToken()
        .switchMap(() => {
          //console.log(req);
          req = this.addAuthHeader(req);
          //console.log(req);
          return next.handle(req);
        });
    }
  }
}))
}
```

I am the results:

[image]

As you can see, the first call fails and the error is an `HttpErrorResponse`, while in the second it also fails but the error is a simple `HttpRequest`

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the first error is an instance of `HttpErrorResponse` while the others are `HttpRequest` so they don't pass into your condition:

```js
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
return next.handle(req).pipe(catchError(err => {
  if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {           // <------ This condition
    // If not HttpErrorResponse, don't go here...
    // ...
  }
 }))
}
```

So that's a good behavior of your interceptor. You need to check if your observables are returning errors well, and if you made them yourself, check that you handle errors with `observer.error(...)`.

Comment: Is that the second (HttpRequest) the browser reports an error, the Network screen marks me the request with a 403, that's why I do not understand why it does not capture it as an error. The call to the services are responding well, since in the first instance if it fails and returns the error.

Comment: I saw in your screenshots that you are logging two lines (59 and 66) of your `app.interceptor.ts` file, please can you show the code with `console.log`s in order to understand your issue better

Comment: Update my code, those are the lines that I am printing.

Comment: Thanks. Something strange is that there's one error (red line) that is emitted by your API call and the last by a polyfill...

Comment: Exactly, that's why I do not understand if it enters the Interceptor as an error or not

Comment: Do you have some Route guards somewhere else in your app?

Comment: No, I do not have anything else

Comment: After looking again to your screenshots, I didn't find anything crazy in it, and I still think there's nothing anormal. It may be an error in `authProvider.loginPartnerToken()`. All logs are ok with successful `HttpRequest`s. So I think it's not an error in your interceptor but an error in another file of your app.

Comment: The error is not the call to update the token, since the service responds well and another token is sent to the last request.